# measurable set and product measure

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that

1.$G$ is measurable with respect to  $m \times m$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$,

Answer (score 1):

So it amounts to show that $g(x,y)=f(x)-y$ is measurable in product space. This can be viewed as the composition with two functions: $F(x,y)=(f(x),y)$, since $f$ is measurable, it is not hard to see that $F$ is also measurable, because we just need to check the $F^{-1}(G\times H)=f^{-1}(G)\times H$ is measurable for open sets $G,H$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Now we let $G(u,v)=u-v$, $G$ is a continuous function, it is a standard exercise to show that $G\circ F$ is measurable provided that the first composition function is continuous. Note that $G\circ F=g$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Oh, I have never thought about showing g(x,y) is measurable in the product space. 
So, does that mean my proof is on the completely wrong direction? or do I need to justify only  g(x,y) is measurable in the product space, keeping my proof?

Comment: You are right, just that you forgot to check the measurability of $g$.